# Query "ALL IN" like. SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, inner-join

I've got this kind of relationship between 4 tables:

- `logs` (*logId*, *logInfo*, *timestamp*,**logTypeId**)
- `logParams` (*logParamId*, *logId*, *value*, *dataTypeId*)
- `books` (*bookId*, *bookName*, *date*...)
- `bookData` (*bookDataId*, *bookId*, *value*, *dataTypeId*)

There's another table called `dataType` (*dataTypeId*, *type*) that tells what kind of data is inside *LogParams* and *BookData* values.

The problem is the following, *all* stuff in *Books* is related to *some* stuff in *Logs*, and it's related by it's extra *data*.

I'm trying to get a query that relates Books with the Log entries of a certain type. Imagine that the *Log* table stores *when and from what url* a book is loaded, but based in its "extra data" instead of its Id (I know it does not make sense, but I can't post my reallife case and this is the better example I can think of).

```
SELECT 
    b.Id, b.bookName, bd.Id, bd.data, 
    bd.DataTypeId, dt.type
FROM 
    books b
INNER JOIN 
    bookData bd ON b.Id = bd.bookId 
INNER JOIN 
    dataType dt ON bd.dataTypeId= dt.Id
WHERE 
    date > GETDATE()
```

The results from this query are related to the result of this other query:

```
SELECT 
    log.Id, log.logInfo, logParams.logId, logParams.Id, 
    logParams.value, logParams.dataTypeId 
FROM 
    logs
INNER JOIN 
    logParams ON log.Id = logParams.logId 
WHERE 
    logTypeId = 4
```

Those queries would throw the same result number. The Log table values and the Books table values would be different but the logParams and bookData values would be the same for 1 log entry and 1 book entry.

Example:

First query result

```
[
   {id: 1, bookName: "Ender's Game", bookDataId: 6, value: "Orson Scott Card", dataTypeId: 6, type: "Author"},
   {id: 1, bookName: "Ender's Game", bookDataId: 7, value: "Amazon", dataTypeId: 8, type: "Seller"},
   {id: 6, bookName: "Ender's Shadow", bookDataId: 9, value: "Orson Scott Card", dataTypeId: 6, type: "Author"},
   {id: 6, bookName: "Ender's Shadow", bookDataId: 15, value: "Book House", dataTypeId: 8, type: "Seller"},
]
```

Second:

```
[
   {"id": "14", "logInfo": "Called from /homePage", "logParamId": "2", "value": "Orson Scott Card", "dataTypeId": "6", "type": "Author",  "logTypeId": "4", "timestamp": "28/02/2015 00:00:00"},
   {"id": "14", "logInfo": "Called from /homePage", "logParamId": "3", "value": "Amazon", "dataTypeId": "8", "type": "Seller", "logTypeId": "4", "timestamp": "28/02/2015 00:00:00"},
   {"id": "65", "logInfo": "Called from /authors", "logParamId": "6", "value": "Orson Scott Card", "dataTypeId": "6", "type": "Author",  "logTypeId": "4", "timestamp": "28/09/2015 00:00:00"},
   {"id": "65", "logInfo": "Called From /authors", "logParamId": "7", "value": "Book House", "dataTypeId": "8", "type": "Seller",  "logTypeId": "4", "timestamp": "28/09/2015 00:00:00"},
   {"id": "16", "logInfo": "Called from /homePage", "logParamId": "11", "value": "Orson Scott Card", "dataTypeId": "6", "type": "Author", "logTypeId": "4", "timestamp": "28/03/2015 00:00:00"},
   {"id": "16", "logInfo": "Called from /homePage", "logParamId": "12", "value": "Amazon", "dataTypeId": "8", "type": "Seller",  "logTypeId": "4", "timestamp": "28/03/2015 00:00:00"},
   {"id": "22", "logInfo": "Called from /homePage", "logParamId": "22", "value": "Orson Scott Card", "dataTypeId": "6", "type": "Author",  "logTypeId": "4", "timestamp": "24/02/2015 00:00:00"},
   {"id": "22", "logInfo": "Called from /homePage", "logParamId": "23", "value": "Amazon", "dataTypeId": "8", "logTypeId": "4","type": "Seller",  "timestamp": "24/02/2015 00:00:00"},
   {"id": "25", "logInfo": "Called from /authors", "logParamId": "32", "value": "Orson Scott Card", "dataTypeId": "6", "type": "Author",  "logTypeId": "4", "timestamp": "21/02/2015 00:00:00"},
   {"id": "25", "logInfo": "Called from /authors", "logParamId": "43", "value": "Book House", "dataTypeId": "8", "logTypeId": "4", "type": "Seller", "timestamp": "21/02/2015 00:00:00"}
]
```

Entries is log can be repeated just with a different timestamp, I mean, Book1 always will be "Called from HOME" but it will appear lots of times cause the timestamp.

So I want to get all the Log entries related to the filtered Books query result and it has to be using the *logParams* and *bookData* values for the "JOIN".

Hope it's more understandable now.

The kind of result I want to get is:

```
[
  {logId: 14},
  {logId: 65},
  {logId: 16},
  {logId: 22},
  {logId: 25},
 ]
```

Cause they're the *logs* that have the same **group** of  values for the extra data as the *books* I filtered with the first query.

To be related if a Book has params of type 6 and 8 with values "Scott Card" and "Amazon" the corresponding Logs must have those same values and **only** those same values, no more no less.

There would be multiple logs with Params "Scott Card" and "Amazon" of type 6 and 8 and just different timestamps.

Comment: First off, it is very hard to read your question with table A and table B (I know you need to be safe with your info, but it isn't helping us to understand you). Second, what is the query you already tried, that way we can also see what your problem is and help you fix it

Comment: You're saying TableA and TableB contain duplicate data?  That they key to join them is not a primary key in one of the tables?

Comment: Tried to explain it with a more specific and understandable example.

Comment: Provide a desired result, in the format you have used for the two separate results given, and based on that data.

Comment: Should `books.Name` (NB: note the different name in query and result) match with `Logs.logInfo`? Enumerate please the *all* the fields that must match.

Comment: Edited the question for clarity's sake. I used concrete columns, and item names so in cause anyone gets here it's  clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query that joins on the different columns that the tables `logParams` and `bookData` have in common, and that requires that each `logParams` record for a specific book has a match in the `bookData` table:

```
SELECT      logParams.LogId
FROM        logParams
INNER JOIN  logs
        ON  logs.logTypeId = 4
        AND logs.Id = logParams.logId 
LEFT JOIN   bookData
        ON  bookData.dataTypeId = logParams.dataTypeId
        AND bookData.data = logParams.data
LEFT JOIN   books 
        ON  books.Id = bookData.bookId
        AND books.date > GETDATE() 
GROUP BY    logParams.LogId
HAVING      COUNT(DISTINCT logParams.dataTypeId) 
          = COUNT(DISTINCT bookData.dataTypeId)
```

The `HAVING` clause enforces what you called the "ALL IN" condition, i.e. it makes sure that all `logParams` records for one `LogId` each match with a record from `bookData`. If there is a `logParams` record that does not match, then the corresponding `Logs` entry is excluded.

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/146b4/4), that outputs these records based on the data presented in the question:

```
LogId
-----
14
16
22
25
65
```

Comment: What I want is to get the logs for the filtered Books. The logs **must** all the same Data than the Books. I'll edit addin an example.

Comment: Updated the examples so it's clear that there's no relationship betwwen logParamId and bookDataId. Both BookData and LogParams are tables to store extra data, it may change in number or parameters/data names but 1 book has to get at least 1 entry on the Log table.

Added a clear example.

Comment: Updated my answer completely, and added a fiddle that has the expected output.

Comment: Yes. That was the GROUP/HAVING magic I was trying to get instead of multiple JOINS and Subqueries. Thanks a lot, you made my day I was really stuck on this.

Comment: The key was that you provided expected results in your question. That is often more telling than 5 paragraphs of text :-)

Comment: Yes, that was key. By the way, one last question, just out of curiosity, is there a way to get only 1 result for every book entry? So the query throws this: logId: [14, 65] instead of [14,16,22,25,65]

Comment: Yes, you would first add the books.if to the select list, group also by that boos.id. This would not change the number of records at this point. Then use the whole thing as sub select, select from that again the bookId, group by it, and select MAX(LogsId) in the select list. That will give 2 records.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96471/discussion-between-astaroth-and-trincot).